# Creating raw_ostream object in LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm-ir

What is the correct way to create a raw_ostream object and use it for printing? I read various articles and the only example I can find is ([How to redirect llvm::outs() to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317177/how-to-redirect-llvmouts-to-file))

```
raw_ostream *output = &outs();
```

which made use of llvm::outs.

Sorry for asking this because I am not too familiar with C++ but had to understand how LLVM works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`llvm::raw_ostream` is an abstract class with two important pure virtual functions implemented by subclasses; `write_impl()` which holds the logic for writing data to the underlying stream and `current_pos()` which returns the position currently being written to in the stream.

LLVM provides the following output stream implementations:

- `outs()` for writing to *stdout*
- `errs()` for writing to *stderr*
- `nulls()` which discards the output (like writing to */dev/null*)
- `raw_fd_ostream(StringRef, std::error_code)` for writing to a file descriptor
- `raw_string_ostream(std::string)` for writing to a *std::string*

The first 3 streams directly return a reference to their stream objects. For example:

```
llvm::raw_ostream &output = llvm::outs();
```

For the other streams, you construct objects the old way. For example:

```
std::string str;
llvm::raw_string_ostream output(str);
```

For printing, every `llvm::Value*` has a `print` method that accepts a `raw_ostream` object.

Comment: Hi, I have a question, How does one set create a raw_ostream object for a file, in order to make the llvm:Value* print function print it to a file?

Comment: @SupriyaBhide You could create an output stream that writes to a file based on `raw_fd_ostream` and pass this output stream object to the print() member function of the Value class. See here for more information on the member functions of the Value class: https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Value.html